# How to remove unused packed images

Tags: saving

Usually I save blend file so that I pack images.
Sometimes tough I find I got blend files with missing referred files.
Obviously I didn't pack them while saving, so the textures are lost.
But how do I remove those lost references from the save file (the .png /.jpg) files are no longer on my system, and I don't like to see the errors of missing files each time I save my file.